# PHP - Unexpected end of input while using ".post" method to insert data into MySQL using laravel5

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I am trying to pass data using ".post" method and then update MySQL table using the passed data. While doing this i am getting a error saying "Unexpected end of input". I am using laravel5 framework.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cl").click(function(){
    var lat=$.trim($('#text1').val());
    $.post("{{ URL::asset('test.php') }}",{
        latitude: lat,
    },function(data, status){
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(data.arrResult[0]);
    });
  }); 
});
```

test.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Test;
error_reporting(0);
function done($arrResult){
        $JSON->arrResult = $arrResult;
        echo json_encode($JSON);
        exit();
    }
//$a = $_POST['latitude'];
$failArray = array();
$failArray[0] = -2;
$failArray[1] = -2;
$ar = array(
       'name' => 'PHP'
      );
Test::insert($ar);
done($failArray); 
?>
```

Test Model:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Test extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'test';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

Right now i am interested only in updating the table with some random text "PHP" (i am not using the passed data now). It is returning the $failArray when i am not using the database part.

Note: I have removed the error_reporting line and i am getting the error 

**Fatal error**:  Class 'App\Test' not found in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Maze2\public\test.php** on line **24**
"

Thanks in advance..

Comment: [firstly, this doesn't help you `error_reporting(0);` this does `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can you also please help me regarding updating the database without any errors.

Comment: is test.php a controller? Why doesn't it have a class declaration? Also what is the directory of your Test Model?

Comment: Thanks every one for your answers. I got it working when i wrote the test PHP file in a controller.